# Python Convert String to List of Lists of Strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have the current string:

```
output = "S.##......\n#.##..###.\n#.###.###.\n#.....###.\n###.#####S"
```

I want to convert it to the following list:

```
coordinates = [['S', '.', '#', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
               ['#', '.', '#', '#', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'],
               ['#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'],
               ['#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'],
               ['#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', 'S']]
```

Basically every time I get a "\n" character, I want the sequence before it to be split like above and put in a separate list item. 
I tried the following:

```
    coordinates = []
    temp = []
    for item in output:
        if item != "\n":
            temp += item
        else:
            coordinates += temp
```

but it doesn't work, neither it works with

```
.append()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension to generate each list of characters between the `\n` delimeter:

```
>>> [list(x) for x in output.split('\n')]
[['S', '.', '#', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['#', '.', '#', '#', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'],
 ['#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'],
 ['#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'],
 ['#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', 'S']]
```

Passing a string `x` to `list` returns a list of the characters in `x`. `output.split('\n')` is one way to break your string `output` into a list of strings which were separated by the newline character `\n`.

**Edit**: The answer written by @MartijnPieters highlighted an important point about splitting stings on `\n` (which I admit I wasn't aware of).

If your string has a trailing `\n` it may be preferable to use `output.splitlines()` to split the string. Here, using `split('\n')` would return an empty string after the final `\n`, whereas `splitlines()` avoids this by default.

Answer (score 4):

Split on newlines with [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) (to avoid producing an empty last line), then call `list()` on each resulting string. You can do this all in one expression with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[list(line) for line in output.splitlines()]
```

Calling `list()` on a string creates a list object of the individual characters:

```
>>> list('foo')
['f', 'o', 'o']
```

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> output = "S.##......\n#.##..###.\n#.###.###.\n#.....###.\n###.#####S"    
>>> [list(line) for line in output.splitlines()]
[['S', '.', '#', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['#', '.', '#', '#', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'], ['#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'], ['#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'], ['#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', 'S']]
>>> pprint(_)
[['S', '.', '#', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['#', '.', '#', '#', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'],
 ['#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'],
 ['#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'],
 ['#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', 'S']]
```

Your attempt fails because you never reset `temp`; you'd need to create a *new* empty list each time you reach `\n`, and use `coordinates.append()` instead of `+=` (which is the same as `coordinates.extend()`:

```
coordinates = []
temp = []
for item in output:
    if item != "\n":
        temp += item
    else:
        coordinates.append(temp)
        temp = []
if temp:
    coordinates.append(temp)
```

You need the last two lines to not miss the last line after the last `'\n'` character.

Comment: Hi Martijn: can you please explain how _ is set?

Comment: @linuxfan: the Python terminal sets `_` to the last echoed result. So any expression you execute that *doesn't* return `None` has the result printed to the terminal, *and* `_` is set.

Comment: I prefer this answer over `.split('\n')` since I'm presuming it's line-ending style agnostic (Windows vs. Unix).

Comment: @DavidSanders: it is.

Comment: @DavidSanders: I used it here because `'foo\nbar\n'.split('\n')` produces a list with *three* elements, but `'foo\nbar\n'.splitlines()` produces a list with only two elements.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ahh, another important distinction.

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` on newlines `'\n'` then convert to lists.

```
output = "S.##......\n#.##..###.\n#.###.###.\n#.....###.\n###.#####S"
coordinates = [list(s) for s in output.split('\n')]

>>> coordinates
[['S', '.', '#', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['#', '.', '#', '#', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'],
 ['#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'],
 ['#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'],
 ['#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', 'S']]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
output = "S.##......\n#.##..###.\n#.###.###.\n#.....###.\n###.#####S"
items = output.split('\n')
final_list = []
for item in items:
    line_list = [c for c in item]
    final_list.append(line_list)


print final_list
```